# Usar Conekta con React Native 0.61

Tags: react-native

Estoy tratando de usar react-native-conekta (https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-conekta) en RN 0.61 pero no funciona.
Ya intente usar el link automatico, link manual, configurar las propiedades de android como indica, pero no puede compilar el proyecto.
Alguien lo ha integrado en RN 0.61 o 0.60.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de Android, despues de instalar, ejecuta `npx react-native link react-native-conekta`, después debes modificar tu Android Manifest, con lo siguiente:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //agrega está línea


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      tools:replace="android:allowBackup"  //agrega está línea
...
```

Y con esto a mi me funciono.